# Vertx with coroutines blocks when reading slow external url

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm quite new to Vert.x and are about to make a little example where I read the current time from some external server everytime when I get a `GET`-request to the root-path. I thought using the `launch` and `awaitResult` will handle the asynchronous part for me but the log just tells me, that the thread is blocking. The request to the external url takes about 5 to 7 seconds. Using a faster url is possible, but I intentionally want to use the slow one to get a feeling for the async aspect of Vert.x.

Can somewone help me out here? What do I do wrong with the coroutines?

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {
    override suspend fun start() {
        val server = vertx.createHttpServer()
        val router = Router.router(vertx)

        router.get("/home").handler { handleGet(it) }

        server.requestHandler {
            router.accept(it)
        }.listen(8080) { }
    }

    private fun handleGet(event: RoutingContext) {
        launch(vertx.dispatcher()) {
            // this request takes about 5 secs the first time
            val url = "my-slow-url"

            val jsonStr = awaitResult<String> { handler ->
                val (_, response) = url.httpGet().responseString()
                val jsonStr = response.data.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(jsonStr))
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But that gives me

```
Feb 22, 2018 10:30:57 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 2025 ms, time limit is 2000
Feb 22, 2018 10:30:58 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 3025 ms, time limit is 2000
Feb 22, 2018 10:30:59 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 4025 ms, time limit is 2000
Feb 22, 2018 10:31:00 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 5026 ms, time limit is 2000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes:

Your function is not suspendable:

```
private fun handleGet(event: RoutingContext) {
```

And you dispatch on EventLoop:

```
launch(vertx.dispatcher()) {
```

Also, I'm not sure how do you actually fetch your URL. I do hope it's non blocking, and then you can use `.await()`:

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines/kotlin/#_awaiting_the_completion_of_vert_x_futures

Comment: Yes, the call `url.httpGet().responseString()` is blocking. I thought that `awaitResult` is exaclty for this situation to make a blocking call async-able

Comment: Then that part needs to be launched either on different thread pool or Verticle. `awaitResult` on EventLoop thread doesn't make much sense.

Comment: handleGet doesn't required to be suspendable

Answer (score 0):

Use `awaitBlocking` for blocking calls like your URL fetch.

`awaitResult` is to get a handler that can be used as syntactic sugar for callback-based functions like the event bus api. So instead of writing a callback you pass the handler you get from `awaitResult` as a parameter. Aka if your underlying code is blocking - wrapping it in an `awaitResult` on the event loop will still cause the event loop to block